# Java and aws-java-sdk-s3 cannot access SdkClientException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a compilation exception when compiling code to generate Presigned url to upload to S3 from Angular5 Client Side.

The code is working very well when I'm using aws-java-sdk. But Because the library is large and We just want to use S3 from aws-java-sdk
I change the dependency to use aws-java-sdk-s3. and after this change the code generate compilations error.

Pom.xml

```
<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.310</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.311</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java Code:

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            ACCESS_KEY,
            SECRET_KEY
    );

    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .build();

        java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
        long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
        // URL will be valid for 5 minutes only.
        milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 10; // Add 10 Mins.
        expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);

        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET, objectKey);
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

        URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
        return url.toString();
```

> Compilation failure
>   [ERROR] S3CredentialService.java:[49,51] error: cannot access SdkClientException

Dependency Tree.

```
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.311:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.311:compile
```

Comment: What is line 49?

Comment: Also: if you run `mvn dependency:tree`, does `aws-java-sdk-s3` indicate `aws-java-sdk-core` as a transitive dependency? If not, does anything else?

Comment: This is Line 49:  URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

Comment: @kdgregory I edited Question to add Dependency tree.

Comment: OK, and it shows pretty clearly that the version of `aws-java-sdk-core` is `1.11.18`, not `1.11.311`. So the next question that you have to answer is _why is that happening?_ Most likely case is that there's a `dependencyManagement` section somewhere, or perhaps you're importing a "bill of materials" (bom) that specifies that version.